# How can I fix "The named parameter 'colors' isn't defined" problem in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor

I'm getting a parameter format error when I use const for gradient's colors.

```
                 Expanded(
                child: OpenContainer(
                  closedElevation: 0,
                  transitionType: ContainerTransitionType.fade,
                  transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                  closedColor: const Color(0xFFE9E9E9),
                  openBuilder: (context, _) {
                    return WorkoutScreen();
                  },
                  closedBuilder: (context, VoidCallback openContainer) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: openContainer,
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 32, right: 32),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            **colors: [
                              const Color(0xFF20008B),
                              const Color(0xFF200087),
                            ],**
                          ),
                        ),
```

Here's an error message: The named parameter 'colors' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'colors'.

[image: exact error image]

Comment: Other than the `**`, is this your exact code (i.e., you copied and pasted it without making any other changes)?  Are you certain that the error is referring to the indicated line?  What version of Flutter are you using?

Comment: Yeah 'colors' word gives me error.                                                                     [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1379], locale tr-TR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2

Comment: I edited my question with picture which shows error. Can you check it please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: After flutter 1.22 update, I am getting error in Lineargradient properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64168427/flutter-after-flutter-1-22-update-i-am-getting-error-in-lineargradient-propert)

Comment: yeah this problem just disappeared after I did everything which write there. Thanks a lot. @Vineet

Answer (score 1):

You can try fixing this by doing a `flutter clean` in the terminal window and then waiting for VSCode to re-analyze your file.

Comment: It didn't help to fix this issue. But tnx for ur comment